# Git ignore with extension but exclude directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder like this:

```
/<root>
|.git/
|3rd party/
|         |a.txt
|.gitignore
|a.txt
```

.gitignore content:

```
*.txt
*.exe
*.dll
*.lib
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/

!3rd party/
```

I want to ignore some kind of file like `exe, dll, lib, txt` in root folder, all subfolder **except** `3rd party/` folder. But the git still ignore file `3rd party/a.txt`.
What is the problem here?
P/s: I also want `Debug`, `Release` folder in `3rd party` directory (if have) not to be ignore. That is, every rule in this .gitignore file will not be apply on `3rd party` folder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to see only text files of `3rd party` directory then add `!3rd party/*.txt` into your `.gitignore`.

After that you need to clear the `cache` too.

`git rm --cached .gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  Also, this is assuming that you concatenate your 3rd party folder, so it is `3rdparty`.

```
*.exe
*.txt
*.lib
!/3rdparty/*.lib
!/3rdparty/*.exe
!/3rdparty/*.txt
```